# Reducing JIT time with recursive calls in Julia

Tags: optimization, julia, jit

I have a recursive function which operates a binary tree of integers, implemented as a nested pair of pairs or ints. My function creates a new tree with a different structure, and calls itself recursively until some condition is met. The issue I'm finding is that the first time the code is run, it takes a really long time to JIT compile all the possible signatures of the function; afterwards it runs fine.

Here is minimal working example:

```
my_tree = ((((6 => 7) => (6 => 7)) => ((7 => 7) => (0 => 7))) => (((8 => 7) => (7 => 7)) => ((8 => 8) => (8 => 0)))) => ((((2 => 4) => 7) => (6 => (0 => 5))) => (((6 => 8) => (2 => 8)) => ((2 => 1) => (4 => 5))))

function tree_reduce(tree::Pair)
    left, right = tree
    left isa Pair && (left = tree_reduce(left))
    right isa Pair && (right = tree_reduce(right))
    return left + right
end

@show my_tree
@show tree_reduce(my_tree)

using MethodAnalysis
methods = methodinstances(tree_reduce)
@show length(methods)
```

Although this example is not perceptually slow, it still generates 9 method instances for:

```
tree_reduce(::Pair{Pair{Pair{Int64, Int64}, Pair{Int64, Int64}}, Pair{Pair{Int64, Int64}, Pair{Int64, Int64}}})
tree_reduce(::Pair{Pair{Int64, Int64}, Pair{Int64, Int64}})
tree_reduce(::Pair{Int64, Int64})
tree_reduce(::Pair{Pair{Pair{Pair{Int64, Int64}, Int64}, Pair{Int64, Pair{Int64, Int64}}}, Pair{Pair{Pair{Int64, Int64}, Pair{Int64, Int64}}, Pair{Pair{Int64, Int64}, Pair{Int64, Int64}}}})
etc ...
```

Is there a way of avoiding this / precompiling / speeding it up / writing a generic function / running particular (part of) a function in an interpreted mode? I would be prepared to make the overall performance of the code slightly works at the pice of having it run faster on the first top-level call to `tree_reduce`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@nospecialize` is an option, but I think in this case, a separate data structure which doesn't capture the whole data structure in its type is in order.  `Pair` is really thought for strongly typed pairs of things, not for large nested structures.

```
julia> abstract type BiTree{T} end
julia> struct Branch{T} <: BiTree{T} 
           left::BiTree{T}
           right::BiTree{T}
       end

julia> struct Leaf{T} <: BiTree{T}
           value::T
       end

julia> Base.foldl(f, b::Branch) = f(foldl(f, b.left), foldl(f, b.right))

julia> Base.foldl(f, l::Leaf) = f(l.value)

julia> (→)(l::Branch, r::Branch) = Branch(l, r) # just for illustration
→ (generic function with 1 method)

julia> (→)(l, r::Branch) = Branch(Leaf(l), r)
→ (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> (→)(l::Branch, r) = Branch(l, Leaf(r))
→ (generic function with 3 methods)

julia> (→)(l, r) = Branch(Leaf(l), Leaf(r))
→ (generic function with 4 methods)

julia> my_tree = ((((6 → 7) → (6 → 7)) → ((7 → 7) → (0 → 7))) → (((8 → 7) → (7 → 7)) → ((8 → 8) → (8 → 0)))) → ((((2 → 4) → 7) → (6 → (0 → 5))) → (((6 → 8) → (2 → 8)) → ((2 → 1) → (4 → 5))));

julia> typeof(my_tree)
Branch{Int64}

julia> foldl(+, my_tree)
160
```

This also has the advantage that you can without danger of breaking anything overload other methods, such as for printing or indexing.

Comment: Great answer, but I think you are missing `abstract type BiTree{T} end` at the beginning.

Comment: This answer is good enough that I adapted it (very slightly) for an answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70479843/does-julia-perform-code-monomorphization-for-recursively-polymorphic-types/70483225#70483225

Answer (score 2):

yes, with `Base.@nospecialize`:

```
function tree_reduce2(Base.@nospecialize(tree::Pair))
    left, right = tree
    left isa Pair && (left = tree_reduce(left))
    right isa Pair && (right = tree_reduce(right))
    return left + right
end

@show my_tree
@show tree_reduce2(my_tree)

using MethodAnalysis
methods = methodinstances(tree_reduce2)
@show length(methods) #1
```

Check the [docs of the macro](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.@nospecialize) to know more of how to use it.

Comment: I wonder if it's worth having a separate specializing method for the base case `Pair{T,U} where {T<:Integer,U<:Integer}`. It wouldn't have the `isa Pair` lines and could be optimized for the types T,U.

Comment: In my book, this kind of idiom with `isa` is just asking for several method definitions. You are just implementing type dispatch by hand.